# Is there any encryption mechanism in Angular 6 that will give the same encrypted output everytime?

Tags: session, encryption, angular6, public-key-encryption

I am trying to register a customer with his mobile number. I am storing the mobile number as encrypted mobile number and also I am maintaining a session to store this encrypted mobile number. Once I come out of the application and try to log in with the same mobile number, my session goes off. So I am not able to take encrypted mobile number from session.

Is there any way that I can create an encryption mechanism to provide the same encrypted output every time for the same mobile number?

This is the encryption mechanism I am using.

```js
public encrypt_mobile(mobile): Observable<any> {
  var salt = crypto.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
  var key = crypto.PBKDF2("123", salt, {
    256: 256 / 32,
    100: 100
  });
  var iv = crypto.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
  var encrypted = crypto.AES.encrypt(mobile, key, {  
    // instead of message try some string or  “9876543210”
    iv: iv,
    padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: crypto.mode.CBC
  });
  var encrypted_mob = salt.toString() + iv.toString() + 
    encrypted.toString();
  console.log("encrypted : ", encrypted_mob);
  return encrypted_mob;
}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what do you have your problem with and what do you want to eventually achieve.

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, please accept and close it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) mode with random IV.

```
mode: crypto.mode.CBC
```

Actually, that is better because it is [probabilistic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption). But CBC mode prevents comparison on encrypted data.

You should use ECB mode of operation to achieve equality test on encrypted data without decryption.

```
mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB
```

The ECB mode don't use/require an IV. However, keep in mind that ECB mode leaks information, See the [penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB)) from Wikipedia.